# Htmlspecialchars gives me syntax error of T_ECHO

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

Im trying to assign this HTML/PHP code to the `$job_type` variable but the software shows an error in the line says Syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO.

Here is the code before i delete the php tags and put single quotes and dots.

```
<div title="<?php echo $item_data['title']; ?>" class="job-meta job-bm-tooltip <?php echo $item_data['class'].' '.$job_bm_job_type; ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-<?php echo $item_data['fa']; ?>"></i> 
    <a href="<?php echo $job_bm_archive_page_link.$permalink_joint.'job_type='.$job_bm_job_type; ?>">
        <?php echo $job_type_list[$job_bm_job_type]; ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

And here is it when i assign it to the `$job_type` variable

```
$job_type .= '<div title="'. echo $item_data['title']; .'" class="job-meta job-bm-tooltip '. echo $item_data['class'].' '.$job_bm_job_type; .'"><i class="fa fa-'. echo $item_data['fa']; .'"></i> <a href="'. echo $job_bm_archive_page_link.$permalink_joint.'job_type='.$job_bm_job_type.'">'. echo $job_type_list[$job_bm_job_type]; .'</a></div>';
```

Anybody sees why i am get the syntax error?

Comment: I believe you're missing a semi-colon at the end of your 4th `echo`

Comment: @Mustafa i tried to put semi0colon at the end of every echo but the syntax error still there

Comment: @JulioPérez no. the $job_type variable is actually empty and it will retrieve that html/php line if a condition is true

Comment: remove all `echo`s in  `$job_type .= ... `. It's a variable assignment, you can not put command in it